# Fixing a stainless steel garden hose connector?

Tags: watering, tools, repair, hoses, tool-maintenance

The picture below will describe this better than I can, but our 100 ft hose just blew apart at the faucet connection and it seems some piece that would go on the inside (maybe a rubber or plastic gasket?) fell out or inside the hose. I figured this should be an easy part to replace but have no idea what part/size I should be looking for. Don’t want to throw out a relatively new 100’ hose just for one small part!

[image: Photo of hose end after it fell apart]

**UPDATE:**

See Polypipe Wrangler's answer below... And here's a picture that shows what he's talking about. I was able to use a wire to pull this out and will try to find a way to secure it better so it doesn't blow out again.

[image: Inner tubing scooped out and reconnected]

Comment: very excellent question & illustrations & repair development!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metal part you are holding is the outer non-kinking protective pipe. There should be a flexible rubbery tube inside. I hope it hasn't retreated far down the pipe because it has to go over the barb on the fitting shown.

Once the tubing is on, then you can see if it just compresses against the outer pipe (most likely) or needs a special part.

Comment: I shone a flashlight down the hose and finally could tell what you were talking about here! The inner hose was down a good foot or so and I was able to scrape it back up with a wire.

Comment: excellent solution & repair suggestions and repair developments!!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps outlined here and repaired the hose. Used a coat hanger  and bent a hook at the end to fish out the the tube which was about a foot from the end. I pushed the tube to the top of the insert and then screwed in the black holder to secure it in place. I did not remove the black holder from the hose.